# How does javascript recognise different targets?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been attempting to get six images to evaluate either "Correct" or "Wrong" depending on which image they're dragged onto. apple, guava and pear(.png) should all evaluate correct when dropped onto sprite1, while pineapple, plum and purple should all evaluate correct when dropped onto sprite2. That said they should also evaluate wrong, when dropped onto the incorrect sprite.

The problem I'm having is that they'll all either evaluate correct or wrong depending on whichever fruit is dropped onto a sprite first. It won't recognise when a fruit is dropped onto the incorrect sprite and I'm not sure what to add to make that happen?

Diagram of problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc7Mg.png

```
<div id="answerBoxes">
<div id="target1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img src="img/sprite1.png"/>
</div>
<div id="target2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img src="img/sprite2.png"/>
</div>
</div> <!-- end of sprite's -->
<div id="whatsWhatContent">
<div id="answers">
<div id="answer1Box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
   <img id="answer1" src="img/apple.png"  draggable="true"    
ondragstart="drag(event)"/></div>

<div id="answer2Box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
   <img id="answer2" src="img/guava.png"  draggable="true" 
ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>

<div id="answer3Box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img id="answer3" src="img/pear.png"  draggable="true" 
ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>

  <div id="answer4Box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img id="answer4" src="img/pineapple.png"  draggable="true" 
ondragstart="drag(event)">

  <div id="answer5Box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img id="answer5" src="img/plum.png"  draggable="true" 
ondragstart="drag(event)">

  <div id="answer6Box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img id="answer6" src="img/purple.png"  draggable="true" 
ondragstart="drag(event)">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

function allowDrop(ev){
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev){
ev.dataTransfer.setData("content", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev){
ev.preventDefault();
var image = ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));

if($('#target1').find('#answer1').length == 1)
{
alert("CORRECT!");
} 
else if ($('#target2').find('#answer2').length == 1)
{
alert("Wrong.");
}
else {
alert("Wrong!");
}
}
```

Comment: The logic seems simple. Your code starts showing "CORRECT" once #answer1 has been added to #target1. What have you tried to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: Well I added the 'else if' statement to perform a check against 'target2' but it doesn't seem to recognise that as a parameter?

Comment: It seemed logical to try:
if($('#target1').find('#answer1', '#answer2', '#answer3').length == 1)
  {
    alert("CORRECT!");
  } 
  else if ($('#target1').find('#answer4', '#answer5', '#answer6').length == 1)
  {
   alert("Wrong.");
  }

too